# How do I prevent unpinning of items from the Windows 10 Start menu?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, start-menu

I would like to know how I can prevent users unpinning items (apps/programs) from Start Menu.

Using Windows 10 Home edition (case is creating master disk and cloning it)

I think this might be possible with Group Policy, but Group Policy Editor is not available for Windows 10 Home edition.

Answered below.

Comment: If you are going to downvote a question please have enough fortitude to leave a comment and explain the vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question as originally written wasn't all that clear. I had edited it for clarity, so it's likely the downvote was due to the question being unclear. There might also be an "unclear what you're asking" flag on it, but I'm not a mod and I can't see flags on the question.

Comment: @Gio_sof Your added details are making it hard to understand your core question.  You're doing well to show your own efforts to solve the problem but please consolidate this information to make your question more readable.

Comment: @Twisty, Thanks for your tips, I think I did what you suggested just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this particular situation (prevent unpinning start menu before creating a master disk and cloning it for standalone ultrabooks) seems to be (see text in following .reg file):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer] "LockedStartLayout"=dword:00000001

This registry setting applies to All Users. (.Reg files are actually text files that can be read by your registry editor (regedit.exe). They are used to add small pieces of information to your computers registry. They can be created in notepad. Execute by clicking on it).

You could apply this by using Powershell in the following way:

New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\policies\microsoft\windows\explorer -Name LockedStartLayout -PropertyType DWord -Value 1 -Force

Users cannot customize their Start Menu while this setting is enabled. If you disable this setting or do not configure it the Start Menu layout won't be changed and users will be able to customize it.

Comment: Short answer: create registry key with regedit, dword value: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\lockedStartLayou‌​t value 1 –Forcce

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you have Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education. The Group Policy Editor is not available in Windows 10 Home.

There is a Group Policy setting, **User Configuration** > **Start Menu and Taskbar** > **Start Layout**, that can be used to lock the Start menu layout. Note that users will not be able to add pin new items to the Start menu when this is enabled. The description for this setting is as follows:

> Specifies the Start layout for users.
>
> This setting lets you specify the Start layout for users and prevents them from changing its configuration. The Start layout you specify must be stored in an XML file that was generated by the **Export-StartLayout** PowerShell cmdlet.
>   To use this setting, you must first manually configure a device's Start layout to the desired look and feel. Once you are done, run the **Export-StartLayout** PowerShell cmdlet on that same device. The cmdlet will generate an XML file representing the layout you configured.
>
> Once the XML file is generated and moved to the desired file path, type the fully qualified path and name of the XML file. You can type a local path, such as `C:\StartLayouts\myLayout.xml` or a UNC path, such as `\\Server\Share\Layout.xml`. If the specified file is not available when the user logs on, the layout won't be changed. Users cannot customize their Start screen while this setting is enabled.
>
> If you disable this setting or do not configure it, the Start screen layout won't be changed and users will be able to customize it.